# How to count characters in text?

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following:

```
let length = 0;

body.split(" ").forEach(element => {
  element.trim();
  length += element.length;
});
```

But I don't want it to count new lines. Seems rather simple, but I've been bashing my head against this for slightly longer than I should have. Couldn't find anything online either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd replace all whitespace with the empty string with a regular expression (`\s` matches all types of whitespace, including newlines), and check the result's length:

```
const { length } = body.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Comment: So, in my head, this works using destructuring and taking the property of the given variable-name, `length`, from the Array that results from the right-hand side?

Comment: @davidThomas yes, exactly. (and not quite awake yet ...)

Comment: using deconstructing for the array prop is genius, would never have thought to do that. wish i could up vote multiple times

Answer (score 2):

`trim` returns a new string, it doesn't mutate the old one, so calculate the length of its result:

```js
let length = 0;

let body = ' w1 w2  w3\n\n\n w4';

body.split(" ").forEach(element => {
  length += element.trim().length;
});

console.log(length);
```